# How to call all methods in the current application that have a certain @Annotation?

Tags: java, reflection

Lets say i have a method in some class in <strike>my application's package</strike> NetBeans project:

```
package wuzzle.woozle;

import org.contoso.frobber.grob.Whiztactular;

@Whiztactular
public void testFizBuzz() {
    if (1 != 0) 
       throw new Exception("Whiztactular failed");
}
```

```
package frob;

import org.contoso.frobber.grob.Whiztactular;

@Whiztactular
public void testfrobFizBuzz() {
    if (1 != 0) 
       throw new Exception("Whiztactular failed");
}
```

```
package grob;

import org.contoso.frobber.grob.Whiztactular;

@Whiztactular
public void testGrobZoom() {
    if (1 != 0) 

       throw new Exception("Whiztactular failed");
}
```

```
package contoso.gurundy;

import org.contoso.frobber.grob.Whiztactular;

@Whiztactular
public void testDingbatWoozle() {
    if (1 != 0) 
       throw new Exception("Whiztactular failed");
       throw new Exception("Whiztactular failed");
}
```

I want to:

- enumerate all classes/methods
- find methods tagged with a specified `@Annotation`
- construct the class
- call the (parameterless) method

How can i do this in Java?

## In .NET it's easy

Here's how you do it in .NET (in pseudo-Java):

```
//Find all methods in all classes tagged with @Test annotation, 
//and add them to a list.
List<MethodInfo> whiztactularMethods = new ArrayList<>();

//Enumerate all assemblies in the current application domain
for (Assembly a : AppDomain.currentDomain.getAssemblies()) {
   //Look at each type (i.e. class) in the assembly
   for (Type t : a.getTypes()) {
      //Look at all methods in the class. 
      for (MethodInfo m : t.getMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)) {
         //If the method has our @Whiztactular annotation defined: add it
         if (m.IsDefined(typeof(org.contoso.frobber.grob.Whiztactular), true)) 
            whiztactularMethods .add(m);
      }
   }
}
```

And now that we have a `List` of all methods with the `@Whiztactular` annotation, it's just a matter of calling them:

```
//Call every test method found above
for (MethodInfo m : whiztactularMethods) {
   Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(m.DeclaringType); //Construct the test object
   m.Invoke(o, null); //call the parameterless Whiztactular method
}
```

What is the JRE equivalent of the above?

## In Delphi it's easy to

When a Delphi application starts, the initializer of each `unit` is called:

```
initialization
   WhiztactularRunner.registerWhiztactularClass(TWuzzleWoozle);
```

So then i can have all my test code register itself.

But Java doesn't have `.java` file initialization; nor does it have `static constructors`.

## The Journey

<kbd>I want JUnit to run tests</kbd>
↓
*JUnit requires tests to be in a special separate project*
↓
<kbd>Use reflection to find the test methods</kbd>
↓
*Reflection requires you to know the name of the packages that all developers have put their tests in*
↓
<kbd>Use Reflections library</kbd>
↓
*Reflections requires you to know the name of the packages that all developers have put their tests in*
↓
<kbd>Create my own Test Annotation, and use reflections to find all methods that are tagged with it</kbd>
↓
*Reflections requires you to know the name of the packages that all developers have put their tests in*
↓
<kbd>Create my own TestCase annotation, and use reflections to find all classes that are tagged with it</kbd>
↓
*Reflections requires you to know the name of the packages that all developers have put their tests in*
↓
<kbd>Create my own TestCase interface, and use reflections to find all classes that implement it</kbd>
↓
*Reflections requires you to know the name of the packages that all developers have put their tests in*
↓
<kbd>Create my own TestCase class, and use reflections to find all classes that extend it</kbd>
↓
*Reflections requires you to know the name of the packages that all developers have put their tests in*
↓
<kbd>Create a static list, and use a static class constructor to register the class with the my TestRunner</kbd>
↓
*Java doesn't have static class constructors*
↓
<kbd>Create a static list, and use the package initializer to register the class with the my TestRunner</kbd>
↓
*Java doesn't have package initializers*
↓
<kbd>Create a static list, and use the events to listen for when a package is loaded, and then register the package with my static list</kbd>
↓
*Java doesn't have package load events*
↓
<kbd>Enumerate all packages</kbd>
↓
*Reflection has no way to enumerate all packages*
↓
<kbd>Ask the class loader that loaded my current class for any other classes it has loaded</kbd>
↓
*Class loader won't know about classes until someone has actually needed them, and you might not even be using the same class loader instance*
↓
<kbd>Enumerate all packages in the current class path</kbd> **⇐ in progress**
↓
<kbd>Enumerate all jar files on the local PC, use a custom class loader to load each one, then get a list of all packages in each one</kbd> **⇐ in progress**
↓
*Spent 4 days so far trying to solve this problem that was solvable in .NET with 5 lines of code, and in Delphi with 3 lines of code*
↓
<kbd>Investigate converting 409 jsp, and 498 java code files to ASP.net and C#</kbd> **⇐ in progress**
↓
<kbd>Give up on having automated unit, functional, and integration tests</kbd> **⇐ in progress**

## Research Effort

- [Get all methods with a particular annotation in a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763472/get-all-methods-with-a-particular-annotation-in-a-package) *(Question isn't about the current package. Accepted answer uses 3rd party library.)*
- [Java seek a method with specific annotation and its annotation element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593597/java-seek-a-method-with-specific-annotation-and-its-annotation-element) *(Question is about a specific class, rather than finding the classes)*
- [How to find annotated methods in a given package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862106/how-to-find-annotated-methods-in-a-given-package)
- [How to run all methods with a given annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996033/how-to-run-all-methods-with-a-given-annotation)
- [getConstructor with no parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579783/getconstructor-with-no-parameters)
- [Call Methods at Runtime Using Java Reflection](https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-reflection)
- [JavaDocs - Invoking Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)
- [Default access modifier for a Java constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541386/default-access-modifier-for-a-java-constructor/13541412#13541412)
- [Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection)
- [Get all methods with a particular annotation in a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763472/get-all-methods-with-a-particular-annotation-in-a-package) *(explains what a package is)*
- [How to find annotated methods in a given package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862106/how-to-find-annotated-methods-in-a-given-package) *(explains what a package is)*
  Additional research effort
- [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory even though I have the right dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669112/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-loggerfactory-even-though-i-have-the-r)
- Oracle: [Handling Initialization Status With Event Handlers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)
- [how to register a java class if the static initializer isn't called till the class is referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090497/how-to-register-a-java-class-if-the-static-initializer-isnt-called-till-the-cla)

---

- [Dynamic object registration in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344337/dynamic-object-registration-in-java)
- [getConstructor with no parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579783/getconstructor-with-no-parameters)
- [Load Jar dynamically and register class(es) in applicationContext at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72599733/load-jar-dynamically-and-register-classes-in-applicationcontext-at-runtime)
- [Is it possible to determine descendants solely through Java reflection API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44562146/is-it-possible-to-determine-descendants-solely-through-java-reflection-api?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Call Methods at Runtime Using Java Reflection](https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-reflection)
- [JavaDocs - Invoking Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)
- [At runtime, find all classes in a Java application that extend a base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205573/at-runtime-find-all-classes-in-a-java-application-that-extend-a-base-class)
- [Default access modifier for a Java constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541386/default-access-modifier-for-a-java-constructor/13541412#13541412)
- [Find Java classes implementing an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435890/find-java-classes-implementing-an-interface)
- [Finding all classes implementing a specific interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991253/finding-all-classes-implementing-a-specific-interface)
- [How does JUnit find tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558081/how-does-junit-find-tests)
- Book: [Unit Testing in Java](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9781558608689/unit-testing-in-java)
- [2/28/1998: JUnit 1.0](https://www.eg.bucknell.edu/%7Ecs475/F2000-S2001/hyde/JUnit/README.html)
- [JUnit Cookbook](https://www.eg.bucknell.edu/%7Ecs475/F2000-S2001/hyde/JUnit/doc/cookbook.htm)
- [How can I get a list of all the implementations of an interface programmatically in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347248/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-implementations-of-an-interface-programmatically)
- [How can I get all Class files in a specific package in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678026/how-can-i-get-all-class-files-in-a-specific-package-in-java)
- [Class Loaders in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-classloaders)
- [How can I enumerate all classes in a package and add them to a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176527/how-can-i-enumerate-all-classes-in-a-package-and-add-them-to-a-list)
- [Java Reflection - Get List of Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944633/java-reflection-get-list-of-packages)
- [Getting the list of packages in a java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500004/getting-the-list-of-packages-in-a-java-project)
- [Tool to convert java to c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896867/tool-to-convert-java-to-c-sharp-code)
- [Package Initialization in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324655/package-initialization-in-java)
- [How to write a package-level static initializer in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980648/how-to-write-a-package-level-static-initializer-in-kotlin)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72795950/java-initialize-all-classes-in-package-without-knowing-names
- https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph
- [What is an initialization block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987428/what-is-an-initialization-block)
- [Package Initialization in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324655/package-initialization-in-java)

Comment: Since you specifically refer to the JUnit 5 test annotation, you may just use JUnit 5’s [`Launcher`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.platform.launcher/org/junit/platform/launcher/Launcher.html) to execute the tests. But if you really want to go low level, it’s [`ReflectionSupport`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.platform.commons/org/junit/platform/commons/support/ReflectionSupport.html) might have the right methods for you.

Comment: Unfortunately JUnit's test runner seems to require that all tests be in a special `package` that you know the name of. And reflection also seems to require you know the name of the package (or packages) that contain tests. The tests can be in any package; packages whose names i do not know.

Comment: There is the [**ServiceLoader**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) class, but that requires creating a configuration file

Comment: `ServiceLoader` is a nice thing when you use modules, as then, you don’t use configuration files anymore; it’s part of the language. E.g. you declare `provides service.Type with implementation.Type;` in the module-info and the compiler will verify that all constraints are met. But it wouldn’t help you with your specific case, as there is no service type (interface or abstract base class) extended by your test classes.

Comment: I don’t see that the `ReflectionSupport` I have linked would require you to know the package, e.g. [this method](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.platform.commons/org/junit/platform/commons/support/ReflectionSupport.html#findAllClassesInClasspathRoot(java.net.URI,java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.function.Predicate)) only requires you to know the class path entry.

Comment: E.g., the following code scans the class path for a class containing a method annotated with `@Test`: `for(String cpEntry: System.getProperty("java.class.path").split(File.pathSeparator)) { for(var cl: ReflectionSupport.findAllClassesInClasspathRoot(Paths.get(cpEntry) .toUri(), cl -> Arrays.stream(cl.getMethods()).anyMatch(m -> m.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class)), str -> true)) { System.out.println(cl); } }`

Comment: "Give up on having automated unit, functional, and integration tests" << sounds like a bad idea. Some cynical side in me wants me to suggest you to just turn off all computers - computers that don't run can't be affected by any bugs.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Oh i absolutely agree with you; which was why i spent 4 business days trying to get automated testing to work - rather than doing, you know, the actual work i'm supposed to be doing. It's ok though, when the code was originally written in 2003 it didn't have any automated tests.

Comment: Yeah, but other requirements are strange too: "Enumerate all jar files on the local PC, use a custom class loader to load each one, then get a list of all packages in each one" - I don't think it is possible to enumerate all assemblies in .NET. I'm not sure about the requirement that Reflections need the package names.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn There may be a disconnect in terminology *(i may not be using the right Java-words)*. But you can see the example code above. Someone just needs to figure out a way for the application to call them. In .NET the solution is trivial (as you can see in the code above). In Java it is not possible (for technical reasons of how the JRE handles classes and when classes become available for reflecting. It's not as elegant, or functional as .NET). But if you can post some code that can find those methods, spread across unknown names of Java *"packages"*: **please** be my guest.

Comment: This is a small POC that I wrote: https://pastebin.com/Nu17sKWs - it finds the annotation as expected. I had to add the `Scanners.MethodsAnnotated` so it would work.

Comment: That code seems to be getting the path to a specific .jar file. (`../testmod/target/testmod-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`)  That falls apart when there are multiple jars whose names i you do not know.

Comment: Yeah, but you can simply scan the file system. You probably would have to do the same thing in .NET anyway. You may also use the current class path - although I did not look into how to do that with reflections.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn You don't have to do the name thing in .NET: you can see the entirety the 5-lines of .NET code that finds all methods.

Comment: Well, as your own comment already says, “Enumerate all assemblies *in the current application domain*”, so it’s not the magic tool that scans the entire hard drive. Replace “application domain” with “class path” and take the one-liner I posted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73045692/how-to-call-all-methods-in-the-current-application-that-have-a-certain-annotati#comment129078739_73045692) two days ago. So, what’s the problem?

Comment: @Holgar [`class ReflectionSupport not found`](https://i.imgur.com/3R2HGcD.png) *(I fixed `var` being an invalid type, so that's not an issue anymore)*

Comment: Did you add the relevant dependency?

Comment: Sure did; you can see in the linked screenshot.

Comment: Ehm, you added JUnit? That is not reflections.

Comment: I did add JUnit, [because ReflectionSupport is part of JUnit, not Reflections](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.platform.commons/org/junit/platform/commons/support/ReflectionSupport.html).

Answer (score 1):

Java and .Net are fundamentally different. The reason this task is not supported in the JVM out of the box is because of JVM's intrinsic lazy class loading; the JVM is not fully aware of every possible class on the classpath and loading all of them would be extraordinarily intensive CPU and Memory wise.

Essentially: What you are asking for *is not possible* without extensive writing of code that can scan avaialable classes on the classpath without loading them and examine their contents. You could implement this yourself, but it will be quite intensive. If you do wish to go that route, the answer you mentioned `How to find annotated methods in a given package?` is likely the easiest method, but will be non-optimal.

All is not lost though: I think the easiest way to accomplish the task you're wanting is to use a library like the following: https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

The Reflections library is able to scan the classpath without actually performing a classload and is quite quick. I use this lib personally for writing frameworks and scanning for developer extensions on startup.

Example:

```
// MethodsAnnotated with @GetMapping
Set<Method> resources = reflections.get(MethodsAnnotated.with(GetMapping.class).as(Method.class));
```

Comment: What would be the Reflections way to do it

Comment: Reflections works internally by examining bytecode without performing an actual classload operation. It's a well written library. If you add the dependency to your project, you can use my code snippet above, but I would take a look at the documentation on the project page. Good luck!

Comment: Is it supposed to be `Reflections`; with a capital **R**? And where is `MethodsAnnotated` declared? Day three. I just want to run test cases; Java makes things so painful at every turn.

Comment: Oh, wait, from the homepage, *"Scanner must be configured in order to be queried, otherwise an empty result is returned"* I was hoping Reflections had solved all these problems. Back to trying to figure out how get JUnit to find its tests.

Comment: If Junit can't find all of it's tests, that's a configuration problem with your pom.xml! You can easily setup the surefire plugin to exclude or include certain tests

Comment: Well that makes sense; i don't *have* a pom.xml file!

Comment: Yes, that's why. JUnit looks by default for Tests by filename. You can configure this behavior by seting up the maven plugin to scan for other tests with different names or different annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ClassGraph](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph). Unlike Reflections, it's (exceptionally) actively maintained and works in many more scenarios (e.g. Reflections will keel over if you try to use it with modules).

```
try (ScanResult scanResult = new ClassGraph()
                               .enableAllInfo()  // Scan classes, methods, fields, annotations
                               .scan()) {        // Start the scan
      for (ClassInfo clazz : scanResult.getClassesWithMethodAnnotation(annotation)) {
          //Just your run-of-the-mill reflection from here
          Class<?> loaded = clazz.loadClass(); //SEE THE NOTE
          //Assumes the default constructor exists. Do what's appropariate if it doesn't.
          Object instance = loaded.getConstructor().newInstance(...);
          //Use the usual clazz.getMethods() and filter by annotation, or use ClassInfo to get closer
          Method annotatedMethod = ...;
          annotatedMethod.invoke(instance);
      }
}
```

**NOTE:** ClassGraph tries its best to figure out what classloader to use when loading classes, but you can still end up in bizarre situations. So, if you know already the correct classloader to use, I'd recommned going with the regular Java reflection here instead, e.g. `Class.forName(clazz.getName(), loader)`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is pretty difficult; but at least it works.

Create a base `TestCase` class:

```
public class TestCase
{
   ...
}
```

For every test case, create a class that descends from **TestCase**:

```
public class DateHelperTests extends TestCase
{
    public void testNow() throws Exception {
        LocalDateTime dt = DateHelper.now();
        checkTrue(dt != null);
    }
}
```

Then, since Java doesn't support reflection, you have to enumerate all the classes yourself:

```
    private static void registerTests() {
        registerTestClass(DateHelperTests.class);
        registerTestClass(ToolkitTests.class);
        registerTestClass(TurboencabulatorTests.class);
    }
```

And now that you have them all registered, you can find them in a common list of your choosing.

Reflection in Java is slightly different:

- rather than being able to discover methods at runtime
- you discover them at code-writing time, and hard-code them in a list

It's all very obvious once you realize that reflection in .NET and Java are fundamentally different.