# How to use Java Reflections for the "current" application?

Tags: java, reflections

The [documentation](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections#usage) for **[Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections)** gives the first line on how to use Reflections:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.my.project");
```

Except i don't know the name of the package. This is a piece of library code that should just be able to scan everything in the current package.

What is the Reflections equivalent of the .NET:

```
//Find all methods in all classes tagged with @Test annotation, 
//and add them to a list.
List<MethodInfo> testMethods = new ArrayList<>();

//Enumerate all assemblies in the current application domain
for (Assembly a : AppDomain.currentDomain.getAssemblies()) {
   //Look at each type (i.e. class) in the assembly
   for (Type t : a.getTypes()) {
      ...
   }
}
```

in other words, the *"current"* package? Or in the parlance of .NET

- `AppDomain.currentDomain`

**Edit**:

- Is it a duplicate? No.
- Is it not a programming question? No
- Does it need details or clarity? No
- Does it need more focus? No
- Is it opinion based? No

## Bonus Reading

- [Get all methods with a particular annotation in a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763472/get-all-methods-with-a-particular-annotation-in-a-package) *(explains what a package is)*
- [How to find annotated methods in a given package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862106/how-to-find-annotated-methods-in-a-given-package) *(explains what a package is)*

And the final straw:

- [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory even though I have the right dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669112/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-loggerfactory-even-though-i-have-the-r)

Comment: Are you looking for `this.getClass().getPackage().getName()`? Or are you looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection?

Comment: Please clearify what you mean by `currentPackage`. Is it of where code resides, or maybe where caller code resides or maybe something even else.

Comment: @Antoniossss I don't know what i mean in Java. I mean the Java equivalent of `AppDomain.currentDomain` where i can then find, at runtime, every class in my "program". In other words: every piece of code that exists until [this](https://i.imgur.com/NFP2Fja.png) folder.

Comment: You need to add some more context. What piece of code are you calling this from? Why do you need to know the name of the package? You can have a package, with class from your source folder, and classes from elsewhere on the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot be done.

Java does not have a [reflection system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming).

## Research Effort

- [Get all methods with a particular annotation in a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763472/get-all-methods-with-a-particular-annotation-in-a-package) *(Question isn't about the current package. Accepted answer uses 3rd party library.)*
- [Java seek a method with specific annotation and its annotation element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593597/java-seek-a-method-with-specific-annotation-and-its-annotation-element) *(Question is about a specific class, rather than finding the classes)*
- [How to find annotated methods in a given package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862106/how-to-find-annotated-methods-in-a-given-package)
- [How to run all methods with a given annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996033/how-to-run-all-methods-with-a-given-annotation)
- [getConstructor with no parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579783/getconstructor-with-no-parameters)
- [Call Methods at Runtime Using Java Reflection](https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-reflection)
- [JavaDocs - Invoking Methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming)
- [Default access modifier for a Java constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541386/default-access-modifier-for-a-java-constructor/13541412#13541412)
- [Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection)
- [Get all methods with a particular annotation in a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763472/get-all-methods-with-a-particular-annotation-in-a-package) *(explains what a package is)*
- [How to find annotated methods in a given package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862106/how-to-find-annotated-methods-in-a-given-package) *(explains what a package is)*
  Additional research effort
- [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory even though I have the right dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669112/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-loggerfactory-even-though-i-have-the-r)
- Oracle: [Handling Initialization Status With Event Handlers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming)
- [how to register a java class if the static initializer isn't called till the class is referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090497/how-to-register-a-java-class-if-the-static-initializer-isnt-called-till-the-cla)

---

- [Dynamic object registration in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344337/dynamic-object-registration-in-java)
- [getConstructor with no parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579783/getconstructor-with-no-parameters)
- [Load Jar dynamically and register class(es) in applicationContext at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72599733/load-jar-dynamically-and-register-classes-in-applicationcontext-at-runtime)
- [Is it possible to determine descendants solely through Java reflection API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44562146/is-it-possible-to-determine-descendants-solely-through-java-reflection-api?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Call Methods at Runtime Using Java Reflection](https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-reflection)
- [JavaDocs - Invoking Methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming)
- [At runtime, find all classes in a Java application that extend a base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205573/at-runtime-find-all-classes-in-a-java-application-that-extend-a-base-class)
- [Default access modifier for a Java constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541386/default-access-modifier-for-a-java-constructor/13541412#13541412)
- [Find Java classes implementing an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435890/find-java-classes-implementing-an-interface)
- [Finding all classes implementing a specific interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991253/finding-all-classes-implementing-a-specific-interface)
- [How does JUnit find tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558081/how-does-junit-find-tests)
- Book: [Unit Testing in Java](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9781558608689/unit-testing-in-java)
- [2/28/1998: JUnit 1.0][2]
- [JUnit Cookbook](https://www.eg.bucknell.edu/%7Ecs475/F2000-S2001/hyde/JUnit/doc/cookbook.htm)
- [How can I get a list of all the implementations of an interface programmatically in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347248/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-implementations-of-an-interface-programmatically)
- [How can I get all Class files in a specific package in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678026/how-can-i-get-all-class-files-in-a-specific-package-in-java)
- [Class Loaders in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-classloaders)
- [How can I enumerate all classes in a package and add them to a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176527/how-can-i-enumerate-all-classes-in-a-package-and-add-them-to-a-list)
- [Java Reflection - Get List of Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944633/java-reflection-get-list-of-packages)
- [Getting the list of packages in a java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500004/getting-the-list-of-packages-in-a-java-project)
- [Tool to convert java to c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896867/tool-to-convert-java-to-c-sharp-code)
- [Package Initialization in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324655/package-initialization-in-java)
- [How to write a package-level static initializer in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980648/how-to-write-a-package-level-static-initializer-in-kotlin)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72795950/java-initialize-all-classes-in-package-without-knowing-names
- https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph
- [What is an initialization block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987428/what-is-an-initialization-block)
- [Package Initialization in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324655/package-initialization-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Java's concept of 'package' is much weaker than .net. In Java, the package containing a class is, for most purposes, just the prefix of the classes name.

OSGi, and recent Java versions with Modules, have a stronger model.

If you read down the documentation to https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections#scan, you will see that there are a number of filters that you can apply to control what this library looks at. If you are writing a library, you can either expose that API to your callers and let them tell you what classes to look at, or decide for yourself what to look at. But there is not requirement to have a single focal Java package as far as I see in that documentation.

Calling `this.getClass().getPackage().getName()` will mean that reflection is only looking at *your* code, not the rest of the application using your library.

Comment: Does that mean that @Progman's suggestion is wrong? If so, *why* is it wrong - why won't it work?

Comment: Nevermind, i see why it's wrong. `getPackage()` only returns the "path" of the class i'm currently in. I need to be able to iterate all code in the project.